# Error: The method 'NavigationBody' isn't defined for the class '_HomePageState'

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface

I am creating desktop app using fluent_ui. I added package to pubspec.yaml and it was doing great before i created NavigationBody class to navigate through pages. Maybe i was using some decrepit version of the package, but it returns error like:

> Error: The method 'NavigationBody' isn't defined for the class
> '_HomePageState'.
>
> - '_HomePageState' is from 'package:specialityapp/presentation/ui/mainpage.dart'
>   ('lib/presentation/ui/mainpage.dart'). Try correcting the name to the
>   name of an existing method, or defining a method named
>   'NavigationBody'.
>   content: NavigationBody(

Seems like this class doesn't exist anymore, since when i hover it it suggests me to create class myself

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  int _currentpage = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return NavigationView(
      appBar: NavigationAppBar(
          title: Container(
            color: bluecol,
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Text(
                  'Choose your speciality',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 32, color: whitecol),
                ),
                const SizedBox(width: 600),
                Flexible(
                    child: TextField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(color: whitecol)),
                          suffixIcon: Icon(
                            Icons.search_outlined,
                            size: 30,
                            color: whitecol,
                          )),
                    )),
                const SizedBox(width: 600),
                Icon(
                  Icons.account_circle,
                  color: whitecol,
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
          backgroundColor: bluecol,
          automaticallyImplyLeading: true),
      pane: NavigationPane(
          size: const NavigationPaneSize(openMinWidth: 250, openMaxWidth: 320),
          onChanged: (index) => setState(() {
            _currentpage = index;
          }),
          selected: _currentpage,
          items: <NavigationPaneItem>[
            PaneItem(
                icon: const Icon(
                  FluentIcons.home,
                  size: 20,
                ),
                title: const Text('Catalog'),
                body: const Text('')),
            PaneItem(
                icon: const Icon(
                  FluentIcons.home,
                  size: 20,
                ),
                title: const Text('Rated'),
                body: const Text('')),
          ]),
      content: NavigationBody(         // error intensifies here
        index: _currentpage,
        children: [

        ]
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NavigationBody no longer exists, use paneBodyBuilder.

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  int _currentpage = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return NavigationView(
      appBar: NavigationAppBar(
          title: Container(
            color: bluecol,
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Text(
                  'Choose your speciality',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 32, color: whitecol),
                ),
                const SizedBox(width: 600),
                Flexible(
                    child: TextField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(color: whitecol)),
                          suffixIcon: Icon(
                            Icons.search_outlined,
                            size: 30,
                            color: whitecol,
                          )),
                    )),
                const SizedBox(width: 600),
                Icon(
                  Icons.account_circle,
                  color: whitecol,
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
          backgroundColor: bluecol,
          automaticallyImplyLeading: true),
      pane: NavigationPane(
          size: const NavigationPaneSize(openMinWidth: 250, openMaxWidth: 320),
          onChanged: (index) => setState(() {
            _currentpage = index;
          }),
          selected: _currentpage,
          items: <NavigationPaneItem>[
            PaneItem(
                icon: const Icon(
                  FluentIcons.home,
                  size: 20,
                ),
                title: const Text('Catalog'),
                body: const Text('')),
            PaneItem(
                icon: const Icon(
                  FluentIcons.home,
                  size: 20,
                ),
                title: const Text('Rated'),
                body: const Text('')),
          ]),
      paneBodyBuilder: (item, body) => ListView(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 20),
          children: const [
            Center(child: Text('op 1')),
            Center(child: Text('op 2')),
          ]
       ),
    );
  }
}
```

The listview is an example